# Json schema auto completion property

Tags: json, xml

I have already created my own schema on intellij environment, and it's working good, but  still have problems in auto completion which provides intellij to the schema,
for example if object "car" defined in json schema then intellij can recognize that there's such object in the schema and intellij will give it as suggestion through out coding json, the problem that I'm facing is that the suggestions are contains all the objects that defined in the schema, but the expectations are to get the objects which defined under the scoop of another object
This is some code of my own schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Pipe File",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "Pipe": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "components": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/components"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "components"
      ]
    },
    "components": {
      "description": "section which defines the pipes in the file",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/setValuesComponent"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/invokeWebServicesComp"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "setValuesComponent": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "setValuesComp"
          ]
        },
        "out": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "dateFormat": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/setValuesCompOut"
            },
            "dateTimeFormat": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/setValuesCompOut"
            },
            "dateFormatBank": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/setValuesCompOut"
            }
          }
        },
        "condition": {
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "type",
        "out"
      ]
    },
    "setValuesCompOut": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "exprValue": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ctxEntry": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "exprConst": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "(Class|class)\\.\\w+\\.\\w+"
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "required": [
            "exprValue"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "ctxEntry"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "value"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "exprConst"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "invokeWebServicesComp": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "invokeWebServices"
          ]
        },
        "mode": {
          "enum": [
            "innerJoin",
            "leftJoin",
            "union",
            "parallelJoin"
          ]
        },
        "method": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "headers": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/invokeWebServicesCompHeaders"
        },
        "dataFilePath": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "restRelativeUrl": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "in": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/invokeWebServicesCompIn"
        },
        "out": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/invokeWebServicesCompOut"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "name",
        "out",
        "in"
      ]
    },
    "invokeWebServicesCompOut": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "doc": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": ".+"
        }
      }
    },
    "invokeWebServicesCompHeaders": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        ".{1,}": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": ".+"
        }
      }
    },
    "invokeWebServicesCompIn": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        ".{1,}": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": ".+"
        }
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "pipes": {
        "description": "section which defines the mandatory pipes object in the file",
        "type": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
          ".{1,}": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pipe"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "pipes"
    ]
  }
}
```

So what I expected is, when the type of object determined to "setValuesComp", the auto completion will suggest the relevant properties, that's mean it will not suggest "in" property which is belong to "invokeWebServicesComp" not "setValuesComponent".[this picture show the auto complete problem in my real environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm7Xb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON schema seems to be invalid. The below JSON content should be present inside object type.

```
"properties": {
  "pipes": {
    "description": "section which defines the mandatory pipes object in the file",
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
      ".{1,}": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Pipe"
      }
    }
  }
},
"required": [
  "pipes"
]
```

In your schema, it is present as part of the "definitions". Please make this correction and then check if you are able to get the suggestions.